# How to keep transaction and ssis package execution to wait for each other?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, transactions, service-broker

Here is a simplified code sample executing an ssis package on reception of a service broker message, which I need to wait for the completion of said package to go further. Problem is : the transaction TR_testSSISOnMsg doesn't commit, due to the "while not exists" loop waiting ssis to complete, and the ssis execution stays "pending" in SSISDB.catalog.executions because its waiting for the transaction to commit... so I end up with two processes waiting for each other to complete... the fine tuning of transactions scopes is not my forte... Any ideas ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testSSISOnMsg]
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TR_testSSISOnMsg
    WHILE(1=1)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testLog
        CREATE TABLE testLog (IdLog UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,dateLog DATETIME,msgLog NVARCHAR(100))

        DECLARE @conv_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                @msg_type sysname;
        WAITFOR (
            RECEIVE TOP (1)
                    @conv_handle = conversation_handle,
                    @msg_type = message_type_name
                FROM [//SQL2016-DMDI/WorkspaceR/testSSIS/File_DemandeSSIS]
        ), TIMEOUT 1000;

        IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TR_testSSISOnMsg;
            BREAK;
        END

        IF @msg_type = N'//SQL2016-DMDI/WorkspaceR/testSSIS/MsgDemandeExec'
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @execution_id bigint,@status int;
            DECLARE @package_name NVARCHAR(100) = N'testPackage.dtsx';

            EXEC SSISDB.catalog.create_execution_VCH
                @folder_name = N'DataScience',
                @project_name = N'ScoresIndexation',
                @package_name = @package_name,
                @execution_id = @execution_id output;

            EXEC SSISDB.catalog.start_execution_VCH @execution_id;

            WHILE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SSISDB.catalog.executions where execution_id = @execution_id and end_time IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO testLog VALUES(NEWID(),GETDATE(),'waiting')
                WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';
            END
        END
        ELSE BEGIN
            END CONVERSATION @conv_handle;
        END
        COMMIT TRANSACTION TR_testSSISOnMsg;
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler to create a SQL Server Agent Job and just have the reception of the message start the job? Then you could just create the separate steps in the job and it would handle the on completion for you.

Comment: I have a SQL Server Agent to "cron" all this, and honestly, I'm using in the same process : the Service Broker, SSIS, and SQL Server R services... I'm not sure adding even more SQL Server Agent jobs in the middle would be "simpler" :D

Comment: Don't add jobs add steps...

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [set_execution_parameter_value] to set your SSIS package to run SYNCHRONIZED.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-set-execution-parameter-value-ssisdb-database

This will go after your create_execution and before start_execution procs:

```
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.create_execution_VCH
    @folder_name = N'DataScience',
    @project_name = N'ScoresIndexation',
    @package_name = @package_name,
    @execution_id = @execution_id output;


EXEC [catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]
    @executionID,
    @object_type=50, 
    @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED',
    @parameter_value= 1

EXEC SSISDB.catalog.start_execution_VCH @execution_id;
```

For your testing, I would remove your waitfor, while not exists select from the executions table, etc. as you shouldn't need them. Sprocs run synchronously, and now your package does too, you shouldn't need any wait or delay. When the package finishes, continue with your sproc.

You may also want to look into using the statuses rather than end time values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database

The status of the operation. The possible values are created (1), running (2), canceled (3), failed (4), pending (5), ended unexpectedly (6), succeeded (7), stopping (8), and completed (9).

Finally, I noticed you are using modified versions of the ssisdb procs. Since we don't know what you have modified, you may (or may not) have made changes that may be causing unknown problems with your query. Just keep in mind while troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.
I need the "while not exists" because in the "complete" procedure (this is a simplified one for testing), as soon as ssis successfully load the data, I will send an answer message on the service broker conversation to trigger another stored procedure working on said data.

Also, I used the test on end_time because I have a check on the status later in the stored procedure too, and I want to skip the cases created, running, etc. which have no end-time.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I have a similar process in my environment. We're using a table type to "queue up" all of the necessary SSIS packages (sometimes it's just 1, sometimes more) and their associated parameters, and run them in SYNC. Hope this helped you solved your issue!

Comment: unfortunately I just tested adding the SYNCHRONIZED parameter and I get the same lock.

Comment: I didn't even notice you are wrapping the entire thing in a transaction. Is the process deadlocked in sp_who2? What is the need for rolling back everything (including logging) with a transaction? This might be relevant https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2699720/fix-you-experience-a-deadlock-condition-when-you-run-multiple-ssis-packages-in-sql-server-2012

Comment: I'm not an expert with transaction, every usage example of the service broker I've seen use them in this way so I did too and I think it's to clean everything in the conversation conveniently if needed to prevent "infinite loops" of messages in the queues.

Comment: found a similar case : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0f91af65-818d-4e9c-9cc8-fcf432bf92ed/catalogstartexecution-synchronized-in-transaction?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: I tested to be sure, but as I thought, when removing the transaction, everything runs well

Comment: I still think your problem is in the waitfor. You are waiting for a message in the queue. Is the package creating that message? The transaction will never commit if you are waiting for the output of the package, and you won't get a value to continue with your statement if it never commits.

Comment: No, no, the waitfor is the normal way to start a stored procedure activated by a service broker messaging queue. When a message is added to the queue, the service broker triggers the stored procedure linked to that queue. (So the waitfor usually end immediately.) 
See here : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839499(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Does anything ever get inserted into testlog? I still think it is a very wrong approach to try to rollback package executions with your logging. That kind of defeats the purpose of logging.

Comment: No, the table is not even created if the transaction is rolled back, but that's what I was expecting.

Comment: I don't think there is much more help I can give you. You are nesting transactions--some of which contain locks, and you have also modified those procs in a way that I cannot see--this is a prime scenario for a deadlock. Your approach to rollback logging along with all of the nested transactions, which include multiple wait elements, is just not a good idea. I don't know what the business requirements are here but I think you really want to reconsider the transaction and/or waits to resolve your problem. The way this is written, you will never get a log entry, it will be rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

You can wait on status this way,

```
-- execute package
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id;

SET @status = (SELECT [Status] FROM SSISDB.[catalog].[executions]
            WHERE execution_id = @execution_id);

-- check package execution result
-- created (1), running (2), canceled (3), failed (4), pending (5), ended unexpectedly (6), succeeded (7), stopping (8), and completed (9)  
WHILE(@status = 1 OR @status = 2 OR @status = 5 OR @status= 8)
BEGIN

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:1'; --'waiting 1 second for Package to finish'

    SET @status = (SELECT [Status] FROM SSISDB.[catalog].[executions]
            WHERE execution_id = @execution_id);
END             

IF @status <> 7 
BEGIN   
    ...
END
```

Comment: How changing the way I wait for the completion of the SSIS package would solve my problem with the transaction ?

Answer (score -1):

This can't work as is (holding the transaction open until SSIS finishes) -- running the SSIS execution happens through a separate external process/connection -- if you don't commit your transaction that creates and starts the execution, the other connection won't be able to see it in order to actually run the execution.

We wanted to do the same thing...what we are going to do for this instead is start the execution asynchronously and commit the transaction, and at the end of the SSIS package send a service broker message saying it's done.  In the activation procedure we use that message to update the status based on the success or failure of the execution.  Note that you can't use SYNCHRONIZED for the same reason -- we wouldn't be able to commit the transaction until the execution is finished, and the execution can't begin actually running until the transaction that kicked it off has committed.

(Note that it still won't be 100% bulletproof because if the SSIS execution starts but is then aborted/server powers off, the process will be stalled because the execution didn't finish.)